# How to select stuff from a SQL database between dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

On my work I try to create a query to get some information out of the SQL database. This is working good, but when I try to use a date range it stops with working.

I have figured out the DATEPART function,

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM 
InlogLog as il 
INNER JOIN 
ComputerIdentity as ci
ON il.Computer = ci.Description 
WHERE ci.Location 
LIKE 'E18%'
AND ci.MakeModelID = 9
AND DATEPART(YY,il.Datum) = 2016
AND DATEPART(MM,il.Datum) = 10 
AND DATEPART(DD,il.Datum) = 03 
ORDER BY il.Computer
```

On the example above, I can't specify a range between two dates.
I also have tried to use this example

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM 
InlogLog as il 
INNER JOIN 
ComputerIdentity as ci
ON il.Computer = ci.Description 
WHERE ci.Location 
LIKE 'E18%'
AND ci.MakeModelID = 9
AND il.Datum = '2016-06-17 09:57:00.000'
```

But this results in a error message

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How can I make this next example work?

```html
SELECT
 * 
FROM 
InlogLog as il 
INNER JOIN 
ComputerIdentity as ci
ON il.Computer = ci.Description 
WHERE ci.Location 
LIKE 'E18%'
AND ci.MakeModelID = 9
AND il.Datum '2016-06-17 09:57:00.000' BETWEEN '2016-06-18 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the il.Datum is varchar type, then you should do a casting for it as follows:

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM 
InlogLog as il 
INNER JOIN 
ComputerIdentity as ci
ON il.Computer = ci.Description 
WHERE ci.Location 
LIKE 'E18%'
AND ci.MakeModelID = 9
AND CONVERT(DATE, ilDatum) >= CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-01')
AND CONVERT(DATE, ilDatum) <= CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-04')
```

Note: I've converted the varchar to date type for the column il.Datum. Without conversion specifically for varchar type, you can't filter the date.

Answer (score 2):

problem is in the syntax (`il.Datum '2016-06-17 09:57:00.000' BETWEEN '2016-06-18 00:00:00.000'`) ,Modify your script like below.

If your column is varchar ,convert it to datetime.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
InlogLog as il 
INNER JOIN 
ComputerIdentity as ci
ON il.Computer = ci.Description 
WHERE ci.Location 
LIKE 'E18%'
AND ci.MakeModelID = 9
AND CAST(il.Datum as datetime) BETWEEN '2016-06-17 09:57:00.000' AND  '2016-06-18 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Datum is of varchar datatype where it should be of datetime datatype

Try this

```
SELECT
 * 
FROM 
InlogLog as il 
INNER JOIN 
ComputerIdentity as ci
ON il.Computer = ci.Description 
WHERE ci.Location 
LIKE 'E18%'
AND ci.MakeModelID = 9
AND il.Datum >='2016-06-17 09:57:00.000' il.Datum<= '2016-06-18 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM InlogLog as il INNER JOIN
 ComputerIdentity as ci 
 ON il.Computer = i.Description WHERE ci.Location
 LIKE 'E18%' AND ci.MakeModelID = 9 AND
 DATEDIFF(DAY,ilDatum,'2016-06-17') <= 0 AND
 DATEDIFF(DAY,ilDatum,'2016-06-18') >=0
```